# fillrect(); is only generating once even tho x and y are dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

only one rectangle is being drawn even tho the x and y value are constanly being changed and fillrect(); is in the loop.

```
    var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var n = 0;
    a = [0,0,0.85,0.2,-0.15],
    b = [0,0,0.04,-0.26,0.28],
    c = [0,0,-0.04,0.23,0.26],
    d = [0,0.16,0.85,0.22,0.24],
    f = [0,1.6,1.6,1.6,0.44],
    x = 1,
    y = 1;
setInterval(function(){ 

ctx.translate(1400/2, 500/2);
i = Math.random();
if (i <= 0.02 ) n = 1;
else if (i > 0.02 && i < .89) n = 2;
else if(i > .89 && i < .96) n = 3;
else n = 4;
x = a[n] * x + b[n] * y;
y = c[n] * x + d[n] * y + f[n];
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillRect( x, y, 1, 1 ); 
ctx.stroke();
console.log(x, y);
}, 50);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/13huvske/

Comment: Can you post a demo so we can see?

Comment: I see a few issues but the context translation is hiding everything out of view. Remove that line and you'll see something on canvas.

Comment: it already displays one rectangle in the middle of the screen, i thought that specific translation put 0,0 in the middle of the canvas.

Comment: Does it display? I don't see anything unless I remove that line. Using Chrome.

Comment: does for me in chrome, change height and width to 10 or something and you can see it, the reason height and width are 1 right now is to replicate pixel control.

Comment: translation was not bringing it off screen but was stoping the the movement of the rectangle tyvm. also what other issues are you seeing?

Comment: I see that you put a semicolon instead of a comma in your variable declarations. I see that `i` is leaking. And also I think you don't need `ctx.beginPath()`. I still can't get your demo to work with the translation, using Chrome 39.

Comment: @elclanrs http://jsfiddle.net/bdmkywam/ it is not acting as expected but at least it is moving now.

Comment: Proper way of drawing a retained path with a transform is to save(), then transform, then beginPath(), then moveTo/lineTo/... then fill/stroke() then end by a restore().  Here you're using a direct command (fillRect), so you don't need beginPath() and stroke/fill .

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you are setting ctx.translate in each cycle of your loop, which will add the origin offset for each cycle.
You could either set the ctx.translate once outside your loop, or you could (and i makes clearing the canvas easier) do ctx.save() before ctx.translate(), and ctx.restore() at the end of your loop.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var n = 0,
a = [0, 0, 0.85, 0.2, -0.15],
b = [0, 0, 0.04, -0.26, 0.28],
c = [0, 0, -0.04, 0.23, 0.26],
d = [0, 0.16, 0.85, 0.22, 0.24],
f = [0, 1.6, 1.6, 1.6, 0.44],
x = 1,
y = 1;
setInterval(function () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    i = Math.random();
    if (i <= 0.02)
        n = 1;
    else if (i > 0.02 && i < .89)
        n = 2;
    else if (i > .89 && i < .96)
        n = 3;
    else
        n = 4;
    x = a[n] * x + b[n] * y;
    y = c[n] * x + d[n] * y + f[n];
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
    ctx.restore();
}, 50);
```

or look at http://jsfiddle.net/72z0f01b/2/

Sorry, i made your rectangle 10x10 instead of 1x1 and red to make it easier to see.
I also added a ctx.clearRect() and removed the ctx.stroke() (which is not needed since you use fillRect()), and i took the width and height from the canvas object instead of hardcoding it (this is a preference thing, it will work without changing that, but now you know thats an option :))

Any more questions? :)

UPDATE: As GameAlchemist mentioned in his comment:
You could also do `ctx.translate(-(canvas.width / 2), -(canvas.height / 2));` instead of save() and restore().

It would look like this:
`setInterval(function () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    // Your render code
    ctx.translate(-(canvas.width / 2), -(canvas.height / 2));
}, 50);`

You can use the one you like the most, doing the latter version is probably faster to compute, however save() and restore() might be easier to read and understand.
What i would do is to use the one i think is the easiest to understand, and if your application runs into performance issues then i would start looking for things to improve.

Comment: As a side comment, another way to restore the context is to perform the invert transform (here translate(-w, -h).) But anyway : Nice first answer, +1, and welcome !

Comment: Thank you, i have updated the post to reflect the information in your comment as well :)